# SAS, RPM, & Bus Speeds

Tags: storage, rpm, sas

I am working on spec'ing out a new Hyper-V server, and I am running into something that I find confusing--I have the following choices:

146GB 15k RPM, SAS, 3Gbps, 3.5"
146GB 10k RPM, SAS, 6Gbps, 2.5"

Why does the 10k drive come only with the lower bus--I would have thought that the 15k drive would come with the 6Gbps bus?

What am I missing?

Thanks-

-Josh

Comment: You can get 15k/6Gbps (and 10k/3Gbps) so this must just be related to where you are doing your shopping - you are just seeing what they have available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top tier of disks typically lags a bit for the newest access methods. Those drives are held to higher tolerances when it comes to manufacture, and "1.0 problems" need not apply.

Answer (score 0):

Plus there are release schedules. Probably the 15k is just not due for a new release. Seriously, though, this is mostly academic - in a random IO scenario it is HARD to use up the 3gbps. You need more than a handfull of discs for that.